# Update a file without uploading it, using paperclip.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use paperclip on a logo model and have the following setup.

```
class Logo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attached,
        :styles => {
        :small => ["170x170>", :jpg], :large => ["400x400>", :jpg]
      }
end
```

If I update the picture of `logo`, the file should be uploaded by paperclip.
However, I do not want it to upload, I only wish to update the logo's attributes in the database.

Do you have any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What about simply doing `logo.some_attribute = "value"` then `logo.save` ?